# getSheetByName seems to get ANY active sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like for the following function to only run on my "Estimate" tab, but it runs on all tabs.  I thought calling the sheet by name would resolve this, but it doesn't.  I'm very new to GAS and have minimal coding experience, so I'm obviously just doing something wrong.

[Here is a link to my sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zUcHYy38-MGSAR_NMOovuMRTloIS2muco7SXQ_dRl3E/edit?usp=sharing)

```js
function onEdit(){

  //https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aOn0VMgG1w
  //var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  //var estss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Estimate');
  //commented out to try the var below...
  //same result
  var estss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Estimate');

  //var catss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Categories');
  //commented out to try the var below...
  //same result
  var catss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Categories');

  var activeCell = estss.getActiveCell();

  if(activeCell.getColumn() == 1 && activeCell.getRow() > 1){

    activeCell.offset(0, 1).clearContent().clearDataValidations();

    var cat = catss.getRange(1,2,1,catss.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    var catIndex = cat[0].indexOf(activeCell.getValue()) + 2;

    if(catIndex != 0){

      var validationRange = catss.getRange(2, catIndex,catss.getLastRow());
      var validationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(validationRange).build();

      activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(validationRule);

    }
  }
}
```

When selecting a category in column A on the "Estimate" tab, the following column (B) should set a data validation with all of the sub-categories (rows below the corresponding category), from the "Categories" tab.  It basically works, but it also works on every other tab.  I would like for it to work on the "Estimate" tab only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the active methods, use the Event object

If your event object is e  -> `function onEdit(e){}`
e.range returns the edited range, then you could use

`e.range.getSheet().getName()` to get the name of the active sheet

then you could use an if statement like

`if(e.range.getSheet().getName() !== 'Sheet 1') return;`

to stop the execution of the script when the active sheet's name isn't `Sheet 1`

Comment: Works great!  Thank you very much!